# Where to find the twitter bootstrap less files?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, padding

I'm trying to find a relatively easy way of adding padding to my containers with Twitter Bootstrap. All works well but at some resolutions, the window doesn't fit the screen. I figure I have to go and compensate for the padding by removing some of the width from various span classes?

This is quite hard work, just the mathematics alone is problematic. For this reason, perhaps it's best to use the less file that Bootstrap apparently comes with.

The only problem is I can't seem to find them anywhere. Do these files actually exist? Unfortunately I only know how to use Less through an app like Codekit as opposed to using the command line.

Alternatively, if anyone else knows of any way to add padding to the container, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most developers would probably clone the [Twitter Bootstrap GitHub repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/).  However, if you're not used to working with **git**, there is [a regular download of the repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/zipball/master).

You also might want to check out the [Twitter Bootstrap Customize Page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), which allows one to edit many of the LESS rules and then have it compile on their server.

Comment: The repo has moved to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases and there you can download a full, non-compiled version that will have the less files in them.

Answer (score 4):

LESS files are in github repo - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less